# Uniform convergence & limiting function f

Tags: calculus

I need to check the uniform convergence of : $ f_n(x)=e^{-x^2+n}$.

I checked the limiting function and got that $f(x)=\infty $ .
And i stuck at this point.
How to check the uniform convergence?

Edited: Sorry it was mistake I mean  $ f_n(x)=e^{-x^2+n}$.
Thanks!

Comment: $$\forall\,x\in\Bbb R\;,\;\;e^{-x^2-n}=\frac{e^{x^2}}{e^n}\xrightarrow [n\to\infty]{}0$$ so how did you get $\,f(x)=\infty\,$ which, of course, makes no sense by itself, either?

Comment: @DonAntonio: That should be $e^{-(x^2+n)}=\dfrac{1}{e^{x^2+n}}$, right?

Comment: @Inceptio Yes, that is right. He/She just forgot the minus sign.

Comment: @DonAntonio Sorry, it was mistake, I have edited the question

Comment: Then there's hardly anything to do: $$e^{-x^2+n}\xrightarrow [n\to\infty]{}\infty$$ so there's no convergence, uniform or not, at all to some function.

Comment: @DonAntonio Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

Hints:

Assume $\,m\ge n\;,\;m,n\in\Bbb N\,$:

$$\left|\;e^{-x^2-n}-e^{-x^2-m}\;\right|=e^{-x^2}\,\frac{e^m-e^n}{e^{n+m}}=e^{-x^2}\,\frac{e^{m-n}-1}{e^m}\xrightarrow[m,n\to\infty]{}0$$

Check now the above is just Cauchy's Condition for uniform convergence...

**Note:** The above answer addresses the original post, with the function $\,e^{-x^2-n}\,$

Comment: Thank you!But in my case $f(x)$ tends to $\infty$

Comment: You surely mean your $\,f_n(x)\,$ tend to infinity...that's true, after you changed your functions .

Comment: Yes, thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

**Hint**

Prove that if $x\mapsto f(x)$ is bounded and $a_n$ is a number sequence tending to $0$ then $g_n =a_n\cdot f$ tend to $0$ uniformly.

Comment: @AD.Thank you!But in my case $f(x)$ tends to $\infty$

Comment: Ahh... it is a living sequence, it suddenly changed nature!